# Setup for testing nested contexts

Tags: rspec

RSpec newbie here - I am trying to make a request spec for a controller which has a number of initial states. To test out the possible permutations I have nested contexts, but they don't work the way I thought they did. I tried poking around at the rspec api to see if things like append_before/prepend_before might help, but they only seem to work within the boundary of a context - not across nesting levels.

What I have written is this:

```
  context 'old A' do
    before { create :a }

    context 'old B' do
      before { create :b }

      context 'old C' do
        before {create :c}
        before {post '/endpoint'}

        it('foos') {assert true}
        it('bars') {assert true}
      end
      context 'no C' do
        before {post '/endpoint'}

        it('foos') {assert true}
        it('bars') {assert true}
      end
    end
    context 'no B' do
        before {post '/endpoint'}

        it('foos') {assert true}
        it('bars') {assert true}
    end
  end
  context 'no A' do
    before { post '/endpoint' }

    it('foos') { assert true }
    it('bars') { assert true }
  end
```

What I'd love to write is something like this:

```
  final_before {post '/endpoint'}
  it_deep('foos') {assert true}
  it_deep('bars') {assert true}
  # implicit foo/bar assertion
  # implicit post
  context 'old A' do
    before { create :a }
    # implicit foo/bar assertion
    # implicit post after creating a

    context 'old B' do
      before { create :b }
      # implicit foo/bar assertion
      # implicit post after creating a and b

      context 'old C' do
        before {create :c}
        # implicit foo/bar assertion
        # implicit post after creating a and b and c
      end
    end
  end
```

What I have already doesn't seem very dry, probably does not fit with the right style for rspecs. Anyone have any recommendations on how I might tidy things up?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on a different pattern of using `let!` because it allows you to override a parent's functionality in a child, while still allowing for inheritance. For example, I can now do things like:

```
let!(:foo) {create :foo}
context 'new foo' do
  let!(:foo) {}
end
```